# Resizing dynamically the `e` of the exponential function

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I've been looking around and found that this question has been asked at least a couple of times, but the solutions are been correct work around.

Let's say that I have a formula with a piece like:

```
e^{\dfrac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t}
```

and for some dumb reason, I'd like to force the argument of the exponential to be shown as a `\dfrac`... worst!!! I refuse to use the `\exp` command to denote the exponential, say I just want to define a command `\myexp` which 'measure' the size of the exponential argument and resize the letter `e` according to the size of the argument.

Is that even possible? How could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want a badly typeset document… Otherwise write `$\exp(thA_s/\rho Vc_p)$`

Comment: hahahaha... Sure, I know, but the thing is... If I were a hard-head guy , who insists in doing so. How could I do it? (if possible) XD

Comment: I surely won't even try. `;-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should probably not be surprised to get negative points for this answer.

Here's something you could do, but I think it results in a very ugly output.  Granted, this is a brute-force approach and could probably be a bit more prettified.  But even then, I think, it would still be ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\myuglybox
\def\mye#1{%%
  \savebox{\myuglybox}{$#1$}%%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\myuglybox}{$\mathrm{e}$}^{\usebox{\myuglybox}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  Scaled (Ick!)                                & Unscaled (Ick!)                              & Preferred \\\midrule
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mye{-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2}$ & $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2}$ & $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2\right)$
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3ex}

Monster content

$\mye{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mye{-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is something that works for you, I'll leave the prettifying to you.

Comment: @egreg, surely from you I would have expected demerits.  ;)

Comment: @A.Ellett Great! I leant how to use `\savebox` and `\resizebox`... thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here, I make the `e` 66.6% of the height+depth of the exponent, and raise the exponent by its depth + .45height above the baseline.  I compare this formulation on the left side to the traditional `$e^{}$` formulation without `\dfrac` on the right side.

EDITED to add strut to argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength\tempdimA
\newlength\tempdimB
\def\myexp#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$\strut#1$}\tempdimA=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax%
  \tempdimB=\dimexpr.45\ht0+\dp0\relax%
  \scaleto{e}{.666\tempdimA}% THE e WILL BE .666 THE HEIGHT+DEPTH OF THE EXPONENT
  \raisebox{\tempdimB}{\box0}}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
{\ttfamily\textbackslash myexp} & \verb|e^{}| \\
$\myexp{\dfrac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t}$ & $e^{\frac {h A_s}{\rho V c_{p}}t}$\\
$\myexp{-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2}$ & $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$\\
$\myexp{\sqrt{b^2-4Ac}}$ & $e^{\sqrt{b^2-4Ac}}$\\
$\myexp{Ax}$ & $e^{Ax}$\\
$\myexp{x}$ & $e^{x}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]